# com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call urlfetch

Tags: java, spring-mvc, twitter4j

Recently I started twitter4j exercise,

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)    
      .setOAuthConsumerKey("***")
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret("***")
      .setOAuthAccessToken("***")
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("***")
      .setHttpConnectionTimeout(100000);
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();//TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    List<Status> statuses;
    try {
        statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline();
        model.put("twitterlist", statuses);
        System.out.println("Showing home timeline.");
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":" +
                               status.getText());
        }
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        model.put("twitterlist", null);
    }
```

I am getting following error

> com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call urlfetch.Fetch in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
>       com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:792)
>       com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:175)
>       com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:172)
>       com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
>       twitter4j.AppEngineHttpResponseImpl.ensureResponseEvaluated(AppEngineHttpResponseImpl.java:117)
>       twitter4j.AppEngineHttpResponseImpl.asJSONArray(AppEngineHttpResponseImpl.java:85)
>       twitter4j.StatusJSONImpl.createStatusList(StatusJSONImpl.java:465)
>       twitter4j.LazyJSONImplFactory$1.createActualResponseList(LazyJSONImplFactory.java:54)
>       twitter4j.LazyResponseList.getTarget(LazyResponseList.java:37)
>       twitter4j.LazyResponseList.iterator(LazyResponseList.java:74)
>       com.controller.front.FrontController.defaulthomepage(FrontController.java:345)
>       com.controller.front.FrontController.homePage(FrontController.java:373)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
>       org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       org.springfram

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same error.

Comment: it is not solved and no answers too...

Comment: I used alternative that is getting tweets using javascript and html5 embed code.